# What is the radius of the Ora Serrata and lens in rabbits?

Tags: anatomy

I'm interesting in estimating the surface area of the hyaloid membrane connecting the vitreous and aqueous chambers. This is a crude estimate however i'm struggling to find parameter values for rabbits.

I have estimated in humans the radius of the Ora Serrata, measured from the
centre of the lens, to be 1 cm. The radius of the lens to be 0.5 cm, giving the surface area of the region between the two to be roughly 2.36cm^2.